# Can default hashCode act as entropy source?

Tags: java

A very strange question: if I needs only one random number for one object, can we use the `hashCode` as entropy source instead of creating a new `Java.util.Random` object and then call `nextInr()`?

Comment: "one random number for one object". What does that mean?

Comment: You can, but I would override the `hashcode` method to make it more complex (random).

Comment: `hashCode` (treated as a random value) can be highly *biased*, e.g. what if `hashCode` is a memory address of the instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation of `hashCode()` is to return the object's identity hash which is provided by the JVM and probably not so random. If `hashCode()` has been overridden, which is quite often the case, the return value is even less random and any implementation that returns a random number for `hashCode()` (even if it is the same for every call on one instance) will most probably break the contract that has been defined for `equals()` and `hashCode()`;

From the JavaDoc:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

So I'd recommend to keep using `java.util.Random` (you could use a single instance) or something different, but *not* `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 2):

An *ideal hash code* should

- be equal for equal instances
- be *different* for unequal instances (in as many cases as it's possible)

Note that the second condition *contradicts* to randomness. Let's imagine
that we have 10 objects. The best `hashCode` implementation returns

```
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

for the instances and so `hashCode` has no *collisions*. However, *random
numbers* will be something like that:

```
  5, 3, 7, 0, 5, 4, 2, 8, 1, 7
```

note *collisions* (two `5`'s and two `7`'s). So a good `hashCode` should be 
inevetably *biased* (in order to *prevent/minimize collisions*) and that's why *should not be used* as a random number associated with the instance. If you *override* `hashCode` such that it returns the associate random value as a hash code, you will actually *spoil* the `hashCode` by adding potential collisions.

So use `hashCode` for hash codes, and `Java.util.Random` for random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`hashCode` will usually give you a very bad random number (if you pass it through the usual statistical tests).

It depends really on your application if it is still ok or not.